# Messages not displayed on modal panel

Tags: jsf, richfaces, message

I got a Problem displaying messages on a modal panel using Spring Webflow and Richfaces. The Messages a published to the Message Context in my action, without a component-id. This works fine on my main page, but if I open a `rich:modalPanel` and click a button there the Message is not displayed.

Can anybody give me a hint why this happens? Do modal panels not support `<rich:messages global="true"/>`

My button looks like:

```
<a4j:commandButton 
    id="add"
    action="add"
    value="#{resourceBundle['button.add']}"
    reRender="adPopupPanel"/>
```

My messages-tag like:

```
<rich:messages globalOnly="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add attributes to your message tag such as **showSummary** and **ShowDetail** and set them as true.